# Is there a way to create a menu inside an established for loop box (C++)

Tags: c++, for-loop, menu, ascii

I am still very new to learning C++, and can't seen to figure out how to add a "for loop menu" inside another for loop box that I have created using ASCII.

I am trying to create a menu with 7 options using an array inside the already constructed box. In my limited knowledge, I think I need to add another for loop with the array, because I already know the number of options? Am I wrong in trying to use a for loop inside a for loop?

Are there any suggestions to where I should place the for loop menu? Or is there a more efficient way to add the menu to the box?

Here is a copy of the code I am printing for the box:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // This is a loop structure for the menu box using ASCII
    // This prints the top left corner of the menu box (ASCII)

    for (int row = 0; row < 1; ++row) {
        cout << char(201);
    }

    // This prints the top border of the menu box (ASCII)

    for (int column = 0; column < 80; ++column) {
        cout << char(205);
    }

    // This prints the top right corner of the menu box (ASCII)

    for (int row = 0; row < 1; ++row) {
        cout << char(187);
    }

    cout << "\n";

    // This prints the left border of the menu box (ASCII)

    for (int row = 0; row < 20; ++row) {
        cout << char(186);

        // This prints spaces inside the menu box

        for (int column = 0; column < 80; ++column) {
            cout << " ";
        }

        // This prints the right border of the menu box (ASCII)
        cout << char(186) << "\n";
    }

    // This will print the bottom left corner of the menu box (ASCII)

    for (int row = 0; row < 1; ++row) {
        cout << char(200);
    }

    // This prints the bottom border of the menu box (ASCII)

    for (int column = 0; column < 80; ++column) {
        cout << char(205);
    }

    // This prints the bottom right corner of the menu box (ASCII)

    for (int row = 0; row < 1; ++row) {
        cout << char(188);
    }

    cout << "\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are the options static? i.e. you know ahead of time what the options would be? You could just define the entire menu, like `const std::string menu = "**********\n* 1. Start *\n* 2. Options *\n* 3. Exit  *\n***********";`

Comment: Tas- yes, I believe they are static. Thank you for responding,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the approach you've chosen, you need to add an array with your menu options and print them instead of spaces inside of the menu box. To save alignment in lines with menu options you can use [setw()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) from `<iomanip>`.

Resulting code can look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int menuWidth = 80;

    // This is a loop structure for the menu box using ASCII
    // This prints the top left corner of the menu box (ASCII)
    cout << char(201);

    // This prints the top border of the menu box (ASCII)
    for (int column = 0; column < menuWidth; ++column) {
        cout << char(205);
    }

    // This prints the top right corner of the menu box (ASCII)
    cout << char(187);
    cout << "\n";

    // array with menu options
    const string menuOptions[] = { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", "Option5", "Option6", "Option7" };

    for (string option : menuOptions)
    {
        cout << char(186) // print left border
            << setw(menuWidth) // set next item width
            << left // set next item aligment
            << option // print menu option string with width and aligment
            << char(186) << "\n"; // print right border
    }


    // This will print the bottom left corner of the menu box (ASCII)
    cout << char(200);

    // This prints the bottom border of the menu box (ASCII)
    for (int column = 0; column < menuWidth; ++column) {
        cout << char(205);
    }

    // This prints the bottom right corner of the menu box (ASCII)
    cout << char(188);
    cout << "\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can play with indentation, or add empty lines for offset in the top or bottom of the menu to make it looks better.

And a few remarks about your code:

- You don't need to use `for` loop to print one symbol (like corners) c:
- Constant values, that you use many times (like the width of the menu) better to save in constants

Comment: LastSymbol0, thank you for your help. I truly appreciate it.